# The probability that exactly three persons take seats having the same numbers as that in their tickets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n+3(n>1)$ seats numbered $1,2,3,4...,n+3$.There are also $n+3$ persons who are holding tickets numbered $1,2,3,....,n+3$.They take seats at random.Find the probability that exactly three persons take seats having the same numbers as that in their tickets.

---

This problem looks like a derangement problem but with some change.
Derangement theorem says if there are $n$ letters and $n$ corresponding envelopes.The number of ways in which letters can be placed in the envelopes(one letter in each envelope) so that no letter is placed in correct envelope is $n![\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+....+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}]$

But in this question,it is asked to find the probability that exactly three persons take seats having the same numbers as that in their tickets.

How should i do this question?

Comment: Choose 3 persons and derange the rest.